# Align 3 columns in mobile, wordpress and Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have 3 columns in one row in WP with Elementor. I need the last one align to right, when mobile layout is active.

[image]

I tried all settings for it, but blind path for me :).

Can you help me how please? Thank you

Pavel

Answer (score 0):

you could try to duplicate the last column, then select the left column and hide it on mobile using the responsive options. You can find them in the advanced settings tab. On desktop and tablet, hide the duplicated column instead.

[image: advanced stettings screenshot]